# User signup with username in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

In my app I updated devise to use `:username` instead of `:email` as validation like described in the [documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-with-something-other-than-their-email-address). I want `:username` to be **unique** but `:email` to be **not unique**.

Registration with `:username` works fine. However if I then want to update my account and provoke a not uniqe email rails throws me the following error:

```
SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: users.email: UPDATE "users" SET "email" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "users"."id" = ?
```

What am I missing here?
Also, I added a validator for :username in my user.rb because without it, it is possible to save identical usernames. Is there a more "Devise"-ish way of doing it?

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  validates :username, uniqueness: true


  def email_required?
    false
  end

  def email_changed?
    false
  end
end
```

**schema.rb**

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.string   "username"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did everything right. Document you followed is also correct one.

Only thing you need extra in your case is non unique email. If you look into devise migration [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/generators/active_record/templates/migration.rb) you can see email is uniquely required at database level also.

So you are getting error on database level. To get rid of this issue you need to manually remove unique constraint from users table for email.

Comment: Ah ok. Sounds logical. Do I also need the whole "add_index 'users', ..."-thing for "username" as well? Because of my second question (about the uniqueness validator).

Comment: If you want db level check for username also then yes. For rails specific it's not needed. Because you already added uniqueness validation in model.

Answer (score 1):

What you're getting is a database level error, as you can see on the `schema.rb` file the index for `email` has implemented `unique: true` key. I think you have to edit Devise migrations or make new ones and remove the unique constraint.